# Filter array of string with select and a bool array

Tags: c#, .net

I need to get all element of a string array where the index in another array of bool is true.
In c#, i was looking Select but i don't know how to use on index

```
String[] ContentArray = {"Id","Name","Username"};
bool[] SelectionArray = {false,true,false};
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
IEnumerable<string> strings =
    ContentArray.Where((str, index) => SelectionArray[index]);
```

Which for your example will yield an `IEnumerable<string>` containing `"Name"`.

However, if your `SelectionArray` is shorter than your `ContentArray`, you will get an index out of bounds exception.

If that's possible, you could simply add a length check, assuming you want an index greater than the length of `SelectionArray` to return `false`:

```
IEnumerable<string> strings =
    ContentArray.Where(
        (str, index) => index < SelectionArray.Length && SelectionArray[index]);
```

Comment: There's an override of `Where` that gives you the [index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549418(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `IEnumerable.Zip()`. Here's a sample:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String[] ContentArray = { "Id", "Name", "Username" };
        bool[] SelectionArray = { false, true, false };

        var selected = ContentArray.Zip(SelectionArray, (s, b) => 
          new Tuple<string, bool>(s, b))
            .Where(tuple => tuple.Item2)
            .Select(tuple => tuple.Item1)
            .ToList();

        foreach (var s in selected)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for Zip, although you could use an anonymous type instead of a tuple

Comment: Yeah - but I think the sample illustrates the point. So many ways to skin this cat...  :)